# .NET Core - Selenium RemoteWebDriver - PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, .net-core

I am trying to run Selenium test using `.net core 2` and `xunit`

As Selenium server I am using docker container as documented here:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Running container with command:
`docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome`

Test code

```
public void Test()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444"), new ChromeOptions());
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
    var s = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
    s.SaveAsFile("screen.jpg");
}
```

When I try to run the test I get exception:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException : Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.SystemWebProxy.GetProxy(Uri destination)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.ProxyAddressIfNecessary(Uri& address, IWebProxy proxy)
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Uri address, IWebProxy proxy)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.get_ServicePoint()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at Automation.LoginTests.Test() in C:\Git\Automation\test\Tests\LoginTests.cs:line 29
```

Same result when I am running on linux (Debian 9) or Windows 10.
Am I doing something wrong? Selenium seems to be able to support .NET Core 2

Comment: Seems to a .NET core issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/140. They have not yet implement this method and this would require modification to Selenium C# binding for it to work

Comment: From the stacktrace it looks like it's failing to detect the proxy defined by the platform. Try to disable the detection: `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an issue on github thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061674/net-core-selenium-remotewebdriver-platformnotsupportedexception?noredirect=1#comment81071441_47061674).

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4770

Workaround with working code is described here:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4770#issuecomment-337370420

Comment: I made the changes but I'm getting the same error. Can you add more details about building the Webdriver.NET solution?